# cassandra keeps running on execute

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I'm currently trying to use Cassandra in a nodejs environement but I don't understand something.

When I'm running my code, after doing a query, the script doesn't exit, it's still running on my terminal.

This is the code I'm using:

```js
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const databaseConfig = require('./config/database.json');

const authProvider = new cassandra.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider(databaseConfig.cassandra.username, databaseConfig.cassandra.password);

const db = new cassandra.Client({
    contactPoints: databaseConfig.cassandra.contactPoints,
    authProvider: authProvider
});

db.execute("INSERT INTO my_keyspace.my_table (id, year, value, country) VALUES (now(), 2010, 100.000, 'TUNISIE');", function(err, result){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
       console.log("azeaea") 
    }
});
```

And this is the output I got
[image]

Is it normal my script keeps running on my terminal (because I didn't closed the query or smthg else I missed) after the request is over ?

Comment: If you want to exit the script you need to add process.exit(0) after Success OR process.exit(1) on err

Comment: I know i can use process.exit(); the question is more like why should I do that? Shouldn't the script just exit on is own after being over ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to shutdown your connection on your db or your script will wait for example another request.

Have a good day,

Answer (score 1):

ok I found why it wasn't exiting it's just that i had to close the connetion after using it with `db.shutdown(function(err, result){})`